# How does one repent from Zina and avoid it?

Tags: sex, zina

If a person commits Zina, is this forgivable? If so, then how is forgiveness attained?

Answer (score 1):

Seek forgiveness from Allah and refrain from such immoral acts, no need to post your sins online. Let the matter remain between you and Allah, the less witness you have the better

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix what has happened already. So, stop trying to fix it and start repenting for your sins. Allah says (what means):

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." [Quran 39:53]

Good deeds efface bad deeds, so try to do more good deeds (e.g. charity, prayer, fast) to efface your sins.

> Ibn Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> A man kissed a woman. So he came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and
>   informed him about it. Then Allah revealed this Ayah: "And perform the
>   Salat, between the two ends of the day and in some hours of the night.
>   Verily, the good deeds efface the evil deeds (i.e., minor sins)."
>   (11:114) The man asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) whether this applies
>   to him only. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "It applies to all of my
>   Ummah."
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].